# Convert a live photo to video on iPhone without using an external app?

Tags: iphone, photos

Is there any way to convert a live photo to a short video without moving the photo off the iPhone and without using any external app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I had to do is update my iOS.

From iOS 13 all that is required is to scroll to the live photo, press the icon of a square with an up arrow in it, and scroll down the 'Save as Video'. No need to pay for other apps.